# How many commutative rings of order $p^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

This question was part of my algebra quiz and I was unable to solve 1 option out of 4. So, I am asking it here.

> There exists exactly 2 commutative rings of order $p^2$ are there?

I have a intuition that it's true as only two groups exists and as we are adding a multiplicative operation so that must be true but it's given false.

So, kindly tell what mistake I am making. I studied algebra from Joseph Gallian.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are (at least) $3$ commutative rings of order $4$.

Aside from $\mathbb F_4$ and $\mathbb Z\big/2\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z\big/2\mathbb Z$ we have the matrices of the form
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    x & y  \\
    0 & x  \\
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

Where $x,y \in \mathbb F_2$, the field of order $2$.

Shouldn't be difficult to demonstrate that these are all of them, though that doesn't matter for your problem.

Answer (score 6):

If the ring $R$ has characteristic $p^2$, then it must be $\mathbb Z/(p^2)$. Otherwise $R$ has characteristic $p$, so there’s a ring homomorphism $\mathbb F_p\to R$ (and so $R$ is an $\mathbb F_p$-algebra). Take any element $x$ not in the image of $\mathbb F_p$. Then there is an algebra homomorphism $\mathbb F_p[t]\to R$, $t\mapsto x$, necessarily surjective by comparing vector space dimensions. The kernel is generated by a monic polynomial $f$ of degree 2, and we see that there are three possibilities. Either $f$ is irreducible, or is a square, or it has two distinct factors. Up to isomorphism the quotient ring depends only on these three possibilities, not on the particular choice of $f$. This gives three more rings: a field, the ring $\mathbb F_p[t]/(t^2)$, or $\mathbb F_p\times\mathbb F_p$.

Comment: Can you check if you see some mistakes in my answer

Answer (score 3):

More fun if $R$ is not assumed unital. $p$ is prime. I think we get the following cases:

- If $char(R) = p^2$ (the least integer such that $\forall r\in R,nr=0$) we get one of $\Bbb{Z}/p^2\Bbb{Z},p\Bbb{Z}/p^3\Bbb{Z},p^2\Bbb{Z}/p^4\Bbb{Z}$.
- Otherwise $char(R)=p$ so $R$ is a two dimensional vector space $R=a\Bbb{F}_p+b\Bbb{F}_p$. Let $Ann(R) = \{ r\in R, \forall s\in R, rs=0\}$.

  - If $Ann(R)=\{0\}$ then looking at how the multiplication by $a$ and $b$ acts on this basis we get an embedding $R\to M_2(\Bbb{F}_p)$ where the image is generated by two commuting matrices. If the characteristic polynomial of one of them is irreducible then $R\cong \Bbb{F}_{p^2}$.

    If the characteristic polynomial of one of them has two distinct roots then in the basis diagonalizing it the two matrices are diagonal and $R=\pmatrix{u&0\\0&v}=\Bbb{F}_p\times \Bbb{F}_p$.

    Otherwise in some basis the two matrices are of the form $\pmatrix{c&d\\0&c}$ so that  $R =\pmatrix{u&v\\0&u}=\Bbb{F}_p[t]/(t^2)$.
  - If $Ann(R)$ has $p^2$ elements then $R =p\Bbb{Z}/p^2\Bbb{Z}\times p\Bbb{Z}/p^2\Bbb{Z}$.
  - Otherwise $Ann(R)$ has $p$ elements, wlog $Ann(R)= b\Bbb{F}_p,ab=b^2=0,a\not \in Ann(R)$, so $a^2\ne 0$, the ideal $aR=a^2\Bbb{F}_p$ is a subring.

    If $a^2\not \in Ann(R)$ then $R =a^2\Bbb{F}_p+b\Bbb{F}_p=\Bbb{F}_p\times p\Bbb{Z}/p^2\Bbb{Z}$.

    The last case is $a^2 \in Ann(R)$, wlog $a^2=b$ together with $ab=b^2=0$ this defines the ring structure of $R$.

Comment: Looks good. The final case can be realised as matrices $\begin{pmatrix}0&u&v\\0&0&u\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$ inside $\mathbb M_3(\mathbb F_p)$. The question remains: why assume associativity?!